# httprequest not been sent to server that works

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor, httprequest, blazor

I am trying to build a client, the server has been tested with postman and it works. My problem is that I am not sending the httpclient and I don't know why, I am completely lost at this point.
It is a simple blazor/razor app:

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(txModel);

```
            var httpContent = new StringContent(json);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("transaction", httpContent);
            return response;
```

base address is ok, checked that.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
   var RequestUri = new Uri(client.BaseAddress.ToString() + "transaction");
   var httpContent =  JsonContent.Create(txModel); 
   var response = await client.PostAsync(RequestUri, httpContent );
```

Comment: not working either, I have already tried. Thanks

Comment: @Iria can you post the code of 'txModel' ?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed, the problem was that I was not saying that it was a json object, instead of:

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(json);
```

I used the following:

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

I changed postman test to text instead of json and I got wrong media type error, I don't know why I was not getting anything from server